Why do my Conditional Fields Pro repeater groups have different formats?
I'm making a conditional form using Conditional Fields Pro for Contact Form 7 in WordPress and my repeater groups are weirdly become a completely different format after the 1st group (and it's ugly as hell). My code creates more of the "How far along is the borrower in acquiring the property? The borrower… *" questions based on the answer to the 1st question, with a maximum of 5 properties.

I tried googling it but its pretty difficult to find anything even close to my issue, I'm assuming because not a ton of people use CF pro for CF7.

Since it's conditional, I guess it's not loading the select properly since it's hidden. Try without the condition for test and see if all fields are properly loaded. If all is good then you can use js to load the necessary classes etc properly for the visuals.

What JS would I use to make the format normal? Also, sort of unrelated, I'm using another JS script which makes the "Please select..." option in drop-down menus unselectable, but it's not working on the repeater groups that are diff format.

I can't tell you what you need to do since you haven't provided any code to look at. And it's all guessing at this point so unless you provide more detailed information you better hire someone to look at it.
